# Object disappearing from the view on save in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Essentially I have a list of objects, and the user is able to add new ones by typing into a textbox.  As the user types, the new object appears.  However, when the user clicks save, the object disappears from the listing.  It is successfully saved to the database (Ruby on Rails/SQLite) so it appears on a full refresh.  Why is it doing this, and how can I get it to stay on the screen when the user presses submit?

Here is some relevant code:

index.hbs

```
<div class="messages">
{{#each userhashtag in controller}}
{{render "userhashtag" userhashtag}}
{{/each}}
{{#link-to 'userhashtags.new'}} Add Hashtag{{/link-to}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

show.hbs

```
{{userhashtag.name}} <button class="btn btn-dancer" type="submit" {{action "destroy"}}>Remove</button><br>
```

new.hbs

```
<form role="form">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='name' class='form-control' name='name' viewName='nameField'}}
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" {{action "save"}} class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

route

```
App.UserhashtagsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('userhashtag');
},
setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model);
},
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('app/templates/userhashtags/new');
},
actions: {
    save: function(){
        return this.controller.get('model').save().then(function(){
            this.transitionTo('userhashtags');
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are manually pushing the new model into your Array collection (not sure how you're managing the collection). I'd suggest moving the #save action into a controller where you manage the list of objects.

```
// assuming "list" is some reference to your collection list within your controller
save: function() {
  this.get('userhashtag').save().then(function(_model){
    list.pushObject(_model);
```